# Golang equivalent of Python's struct.pack / struct.unpack

Tags: go

In Python, using the `struct` module, I can do something like this to get a packed representation of a value as a string:

```
import struct
print struct.pack('L', 64)
"@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
struct.unpack('L', '@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')
(64,)
```

I'd like to do something similar in Go, except I'm a little unclear on how to do so. I know I can do something like this:

```
import (
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
)

bs := make([]byte, 8)
binary.PutUvarint(bs, uint64(64))
fmt.Printf("%s", bs)
"@"
```

But that's very different and probably not what I want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, "encoding/binary" is what you want, you just don't want the variable length format.

https://go.dev/play/p/e81LuPO_JR

```
bs := make([]byte, 8)
binary.LittleEndian.PutUint64(bs, uint64(64))
fmt.Printf("%#v\n", bs)

i := binary.LittleEndian.Uint64(bs)
fmt.Println(i)
```

Comment: @cliquot-the-dog, JFTR keep in mind that `encoding/binary` is able to marshal and unmarshal binary data from values/into variables of custom `struct` types (by `reflect`ing over their structure), so one often can "unpack" complex binary strings right into custom `struct`ures and back.

Comment: @xaav: I'm not sure what you mean, this example itself decodes a non-zero argument.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple interesting solutions.

1st is gist that's simple to follow and its limitations are clear:

https://gist.github.com/cloveryume/9a59e8d77f5836f11720#file-golang_struct_packed-go

2nd is a package that tries to the job of packing:

https://github.com/lunixbochs/struc